# Is there any shortcut for with open(fl, 'r') as f: data = f.read() in standard library?

Tags: python

I take my self repeating a lot this pattern:

```
with open(fil, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
# do something with data
```

Anybody knows of any shortcut for this in the standard library? Anything like:

```
def fdata(fil):
    with open(fil, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Comment: If you're repeating it often enough and what you do with it has a pattern, I recommend that you make a method/class out of it. Like what you said, so that you won't repeat yourself.

Comment: The problem of this is that I have to repeat the definition for each project or create a library with 3 lines. Sticking with the standard library I avoid a lot of code duplication.

Comment: While I agree that @Phydeaux answers the question, his solution is just two lines shorter than writing the `fdata` function yourself, and it imports a whole module just to do a simple three-line operation. What exactly is the downside of manually writing `fdata`? Your "code duplication" issue makes little sense; you duplicate the import statement, as opposed to the three lines of code, but now you have an external dependency...

Comment: Not external because it's in the standard library. If the standard library provides one way of doing something with less code I will prefer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text) (3.5 and up):

```
from pathlib import Path
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
```

For older versions of python, you can install [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/).

Otherwise, you will need to define your own function as per your example.